# python load data from file in one line

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have some data in a file like that :

```
18499 0.00822792
14606 0.00778273
3926 0.00287178
2013 0.00130196
3053 0.000829384
16320 0.00249749
```

I would like to load and parse data in python in one line, this what I wrote for the moment:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    data = f.read()
data = [line.split() for line in data.split('\n') if line]
x = list(map((lambda x:float(x[0])), data))
y = list(map((lambda x:float(x[1])), data))
```

So the goal is to have something like:

```
x, y = ....
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have now? If it works, and you just want a review of your implementation, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: how about `pandas.from_csv('yourpath').to_csv('pathtosave')`, or something along those lines.

Comment: It's doable on one line, but be aware of PEP-0020, specifically "Readability counts".

Comment: There you are: `with open(input_file) as f: data = f.read(); data = [line.split() for line in data.split('\n') if line]; x = list(map((lambda x:float(x[0])), data)); y = list(map((lambda x:float(x[1])), data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    x,y = zip(*[map(float,line.split()) for line in f])
print x
print y
```

I think I got my parentheses balanced there ... but just cause you can doesnt mean you should ...

[edit] fixed the code to actually work...

Comment: I agree hence my annotation that just because you can doesnt mean you should

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
xy = numpy.loadtxt('input_file.txt');
x, y = xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> x, y = map(list, izip(*(line.split() for line in open(input_file) if line)))
>>> x
['18499', '14606', '3926', '2013', '3053', '16320']
>>> y
['0.00822792', '0.00778273', '0.00287178', '0.00130196', '0.000829384', '0.00249749']
```